# How to sqlite + listview + onListItemClick start new Activity? read error by Cursor

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview, cursor

With the help of this [tutorial](http://www.zoomified.com/articles/android/android-list-of-tutorials.php) i have made an app that has 3 activities.
In the fisrt activity(Import) i just import some values to a sqlite database.

This is my DatabaseHelper class:

```
   public class DatabaseHelper_bp extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "bpDB";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database creation sql statement
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table bp_import ( _id integer primary key, datetime text not null, systolic text not null, diastolic text not null, pulses text not null, notes text not null);";

    public DatabaseHelper_bp(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    // Method is called during creation of the database
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    }

    // Method is called during an upgrade of the database,
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int oldVersion,
            int newVersion) {
        Log.w(DatabaseHelper_bp.class.getName(),
                "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                        + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS bp_import");
        onCreate(database);
    }
}
```

And my  DAO class for my measures/values:

```
    public class BpDAO {

    private DatabaseHelper_bp dbHelper;

    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    /**
     * Movie table related constants.
     */
    public final static String bp_TABLE = "bp_import";
    public final static String bp_ID = "_id";
    public final static String bp_DT = "datetime";
    public final static String bp_SYS = "systolic";
    public final static String bp_DIA = "diastolic";
    public final static String bp_PUL = "pulses";
    public final static String bp_NOT = "notes";

    /**
     * 
     * @param context
     */
    public BpDAO(Context context) {
        dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper_bp(context);
        database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    /**
     * \ Creates a new blood pressure measure
     * 
     * @param datetime
     * @param systolic
     * @param diastolic
     * @param pulses
     * @param notes
     * @return
     */
    public long importBP(String datetime, String systolic, String diastolic,
            String pulses, String notes) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(bp_DT, datetime);
        values.put(bp_SYS, systolic);
        values.put(bp_DIA, diastolic);
        values.put(bp_PUL, pulses);
        values.put(bp_NOT, notes);
        return database.insert(bp_TABLE, null, values);
    }

    /**
     * Fetch all movies
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public Cursor fetchAll_bp() {
        Cursor mCursor = database.query(true, bp_TABLE, new String[] { bp_SYS,
                bp_DIA, bp_DT, bp_ID }, null, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;
    }
}
```

In the second activity(History) i have a List activity with the some values of each row of my database.All work well here.The list is populated by the database,all ok[image]

BUT my **problem** is when i try **onListItemClick** to start a new 3 Activity(Detailed Infos) and pass to it all the values of the selected measure (ListItem), **the app force closes**!

Here is the code of 2 Activity(history):

```
public class HistoryActivity extends ListActivity {

private BpDAO dao;

private SimpleCursorAdapter dbAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    dao = new BpDAO(this);
    Cursor bpList = dao.fetchAll_bp();
    String[] from = new String[] { BpDAO.bp_SYS, BpDAO.bp_DIA, BpDAO.bp_DT };
    int[] target = new int[] { R.id.bpSysHolder, R.id.bpDiaHolder,
            R.id.bpDtHolder };
    dbAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.history_bp, bpList,
            from, target);
    setListAdapter(dbAdapter);
}
    //above is all good!
// try to make new activity on click - let's
// see...down here is the problem!
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View view, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, view, position, id);
    Log.d("BPT", "Selected bp id =" + id);
            // log says that i have selected an item with id : 11 

    Cursor selectedBpDetails = (Cursor) l.getItemAtPosition(position);

    String bp_DT = selectedBpDetails.getString(selectedBpDetails
            .getColumnIndex(BpDAO.bp_DT));
    String bp_SYS = selectedBpDetails.getString(selectedBpDetails
            .getColumnIndex(BpDAO.bp_SYS));
    String bp_DIA = selectedBpDetails.getString(selectedBpDetails
            .getColumnIndex(BpDAO.bp_DIA));
    String bp_PUL = selectedBpDetails.getString(selectedBpDetails
            .getColumnIndex(BpDAO.bp_PUL));
    String bp_NOT = selectedBpDetails.getString(selectedBpDetails
            .getColumnIndex(BpDAO.bp_NOT));

    Log.d("BPT", "Selected bp details = { date=" + bp_DT + ", systolic="
            + bp_SYS + ", diastolic=" + bp_DIA + ", pulses=" + bp_PUL
            + ", notes=" + bp_NOT + " }");

    Intent intent = new Intent(HistoryActivity.this, FromHistory.class);
    intent.putExtra("bp_SYS", bp_SYS);
    intent.putExtra("bp_DIA", bp_DIA);
    intent.putExtra("bp_DT", bp_DT);
    intent.putExtra("bp_PUL", bp_PUL);
    intent.putExtra("bp_NOT", bp_NOT);
    startActivity(intent);
}
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

}

This is the logcat:

```
16:50:48.513: D/BPT(562): Selected bp id =11
16:50:48.513: **E/CursorWindow(562): Failed to read row 1, column -1 from a CursorWindow which has 13 rows, 4 columns.**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your database query method fetchAll_bp() in the BpDAO class, it looks like you forgot to include notes (bp_NOT) in the query.  So suspect it is failing because your onClickListener is looking for bp_NOT in the cursor, which it does not contain.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Cursor selectedBpDetails = (Cursor) l.getItemAtPosition(position);
if (selectedBpDetails.getCursor() > 0) {
    selectedBpDetails.moveToFirst();

    String bp_DT = selectedBpDetails.getString(selectedBpDetails
            .getColumnIndex(BpDAO.bp_DT));
    String bp_SYS = selectedBpDetails.getString(selectedBpDetails
            .getColumnIndex(BpDAO.bp_SYS));
    String bp_DIA = selectedBpDetails.getString(selectedBpDetails
            .getColumnIndex(BpDAO.bp_DIA));
    String bp_PUL = selectedBpDetails.getString(selectedBpDetails
            .getColumnIndex(BpDAO.bp_PUL));
    String bp_NOT = selectedBpDetails.getString(selectedBpDetails
            .getColumnIndex(BpDAO.bp_NOT));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The function fetchAll_bp in the database table doesn't contain any entry for notes, it might be the reason for getting the error.